# How to convert string into floating point value in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, floating-point

I have a scenario where i am fetching version of app  and converting that value into double.
The value of my JSON is in this format '1.0.0' so when i converting it to double it just displays '1' instead of '1.0.0'.
This is my code:

```
 double appVersion = [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary]
        objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"] doubleValue];
NSLog(@"%f",appVersion);
```

How to get '1.0.0' in my double value.
Thanks

Comment: How can "1.0.0" possibly be interpreted as a double ???

Comment: Why are you converting it to a double anyway?!

Answer (score 4):

The app version is in the form `major.minor.patchlevel`, which is not a floating point number.  Instead you have to read the complete string and split up the components, something like:

```
NSString *appVersion = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary]
        objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
NSArray *components = [appVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
NSAssert([components count] == 3, @"Something bad happened");
unsigned major = [components[0] unsignedValue];
unsigned minor = [components[1] unsignedValue];
unsigned patchlevel = [components[2] unsignedValue];
```